# Show date in specific format date from code?

Tags: angular, typescript, datetime, date-format

I have an angular2 v4 app and I have to show a date in a specific format.

I have this in my component:

```
currentDate: Date = new Date();
```

And in my HTML I have this.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [(ngModel)]="currentReport.fromDate" type="text"/>
</mat-form-field>
```

But In running time, the input look like this:

```
Sat Nov 17 2018 17:35:26 GMT-0600 (hora estándar central)
```

How to show the date in format `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm` using ngModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to format the `Date` object to a `string`. One way to do that is with moment `.format` (https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/)

```
currentDate: Date = moment(new Date()).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm')
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only thing you need then initialize it like this in your ts file `currentDate: string = new Date().toLocaleString();`

if you need other date formats too then use a library like moment